# How to use Handlebars in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, handlebars.js, angular12

I used to be able to use Handlebars in Angular 11 but since I updated to Angular 12 I'm getting the following errors:

> ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js:25:2-9 - Warning: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
> ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js:23:38-45 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '/node_modules/handlebars/lib'

I'm importing Handlebars like

```
import * as handlebars from 'handlebars';
```

I have tried to add Handlebars to the `angular.json` as following but nothing seems to be working.

```
"node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with handlebars specifically in relation to angular? The question is a bit confusing as angular has its own templating system for rendering data for component templates.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm using handlebarsjs to validate user input for email templates which have to be written in handlebars.

Comment: You need to share more code. It's not clear what angular is doing in your application, how that data is provided to the server and/or handlebars template. With angular forms you can validate input before submitting the form or sending HTTP request. Perhaps show your angular form and what you are trying to validate.

Comment: That being said, your import seems fine when just adding `handlebars` as a dependency in the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvbih4

Answer (score 2):

Importing from `handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars` or `handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars` works but the `handlebars` package has to be added to the `allowedCommonJsDependencies`.

Comment: This answer does not work well, compilation failed on 

```Could not find a declaration file for module 'handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars'. '/Users/......./node_modules/handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/handlebars` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'handlebars/dist/amd/handlebars';
```.

 Is there please some another step?

Comment: I got it to compile by adding a `handlebars.d.ts` file with these contents:

`declare module 'handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars' { import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars'; export const precompile: typeof Handlebars.precompile; export const compile: typeof Handlebars.compile; }`

Comment: @JoeSkeen Did you manage to make it work? for me, compiles but, I'm getting an error with `node_modules`, working on an Angular project

Comment: Yes, let me look it up and I will share a gist